# While Loop does not go to next line of text document - Java

Tags: java

```
public class LoopingMediaLib
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String songInfo = MediaFile.readString();
        while(songInfo != null)
        {
            System.out.println(songInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

The text document has four lines:
Johnny B.Goode|7
Controlla|9
Happy Birthday|2
Love Story|2

Not only does it not terminate it only reads the first line of text over and over again outputting Johnny B.Goode|7 infinitely.

Comment: You aren't assigning a new value to `songInfo` inside the loop, so it will never change.

Comment: please add the static MediaFile class including the readString method.

Answer (score 4):

the reading of the songInfo needs to be in the loop

```
String songInfo = MediaFile.readString();
while(songInfo != null)
{
        System.out.println(songInfo);
        songInfo = MediaFile.readString()
}
```

or

```
String songInfo = null;
while((songInfo = MediaFile.readString()) != null)
{
        System.out.println(songInfo);
}
```